# R shiny: How to use removeUI in shiny module to hide action button

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity, shinymodules

I want to hide an action button once it is clicked and when the input is not empty.

Similar question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75749132/shiny-how-to-hide-action-button-once-it-is-clicked-and-the-input-is-not-empty), and the provided solutions works very well.

However, I don't know how to make it work in a shiny module.

Here is my example code:

```r
# module UI
choice_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    textInput(inputId = ns("myInput"), label = "write something"),
    actionButton(inputId = ns("click"), label = "click me"),
    verbatimTextOutput(outputId = ns("text"))
    )
  }

# module server
choice_server <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session){
    observeEvent(input$click, {
      x <- input$myInput
      output$text <- renderPrint({x})
      req(x)
      removeUI(selector = paste0("#click", id), session = session)
      })
    })
  }

# Application
library(shiny)
app_ui <- function() {
  fluidPage(
    choice_ui("choice_ui_1")
  )
}

app_server <- function(input, output, session) {
  choice_server("choice_ui_1")
}

shinyApp(app_ui, app_server)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the module server, get the session namespace:

```r
ns <- session$ns
```

Use it in `removeUI()` as follows:

```r
removeUI(selector = paste0("#", ns("click")), session = session)
```

Here's a complete reprex:

```r
# module UI
choice_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    textInput(inputId = ns("myInput"), label = "write something"),
    actionButton(inputId = ns("click"), label = "click me"),
    verbatimTextOutput(outputId = ns("text"))
  )
}

# module server
choice_server <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    ns <- session$ns
    observeEvent(input$click, {
      x <- input$myInput
      output$text <- renderPrint({
        x
      })
      req(x)
      removeUI(selector = paste0("#", ns("click")), session = session)
    })
  })
}

# Application
library(shiny)
app_ui <- function() {
  fluidPage(
    choice_ui("choice_ui_1")
  )
}

app_server <- function(input, output, session) {
  choice_server("choice_ui_1")
}

shinyApp(app_ui, app_server)
```